# bits to bytes python

Tags: python, byte, format, bit

Хочу бит перевести в байт формат, таким способом

```
b = 10
a = b.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')
print(a)
```

Но в ответе получаю **b'\n'** (это эквивалентно 1010 в битах) , вместо ожидаемого **b'\x02'**.

Как я понял проблема в том, что питон переводит 10 формата int в байты, а мне нужно 10 bit перевести.
Так вот, как мне указать, что мой вводимый формат бит(если это возможно). Или есть ли какой другой способ решения нужной мне задачи.

Comment: Если байт всего один, то можно `bytes([0b10])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы задаёте переменной b значение в десятичной системе, а значит в двоичной системе значение переменной равно 1010, и этому соответствует символ новой строки (в Python представление байтов \xNN заменяется символом, когда есть читаемый символ соответствующий числу). Чтобы задать значение переменной в двоичной системе, необходимо указать перед цифрами `0b`. Таким образом:

```
b = 0b10 # то же самое, что и b = 2
a = b.to_bytes(1, byteorder='big')
print(a) # b'\x02'
```

Comment: да уж, все оказалось куда проще.. упустил из виду указатель на двоичное число.
Спасибо большое))

Answer (score 0):

такой вариант тоже помог

```
b = '10'
a = int(b, 2).to_bytes(1, byteorder='big') # указали на то, что число находится в двоичной системе 
print(a)
```